# disabled thumbnail using css bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to disabled this thumbnail using bootstrap class:

```
<div class="row row-menu-s0s1">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 thumb">
       <a class="thumbnail" href="<c:url value='/${area}/link'/>">
          <img class="img-responsive img-menu" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/img/menu-box-02.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

***to clarify:** I would like some of thumbnail inside my pages to be disabled because of certain reason. so far ive been trying to add `disabled` class to `<a>`,`div.thumb`,and even `img`. however that doesnt works. the link still active and the pointer still showing i need something to give idea to user that this thumbnail is not active and to stop link from working.

***the answer:** while my initial idea is to fade the thumbnail and return pointer to normal cursor. i realised from the answer i could just use css `pointer-events: none;cursor: not-allowed;` with combination `<a class=disabled>` and some jquery :

```
$('a.disabled').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

while this might be just a workaround not real proper way. but im more than contented to accept any working answer right now.

Comment: When you say disable the thumbnail, what do you mean?  Why not just remove the link if you want it "disabled"?

Comment: remove the link could work but it change css of thumbnail

Comment: i want the `img` in `a` tag to fade a bit when disabled. and the pointer when hover over thumbnail become arrow not 'hand'

Comment: use a span that has the class thumbnail and then style the span the same as an anchor and use `cursor:` to change the pointer style

Comment: @rlemon@lolka_bolka@Pete@dippas@Serlite Please revise. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [pointer-events: none;](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

```
.thumb a {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: that doesnt work. pointer still showing when hover over thumbnail.

Comment: hey! have you looking for cursor: not-allowed; ?